# C# Windows Form Application - value not printing in textbox for each time

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, windows-forms-designer, form-control

Value not printing in textbox for each time..  Iam able to see last value only (10) in textbox.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++)
       {
         textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
         Thread.Sleep(100);
       }
    }
```

Comment: You replace the contents of the `TextBox` `textBox1` every time through the loop, that's why you're only seeing the last value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# Window application, control values are render after event is executed.

After your click event textbox is displaying last value that is updated.

If you want to render text-box value during event execution.You have to call refresh method of text-box to render value.

Use this..
You have to refresh textbox control.

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
 {
    textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
    textBox1.Refresh();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
 }
```

Comment: Hi sangram parmar, Thank u very much.. its working fyn in Windows Form Application, how can i achieve this in WPF..?

Answer (score -1):

each time your code runs it sets all the text in the textbox to `i`, you need to use:

`textBox1.Text += i.ToString();`

instead of

`textBox1.Text = i.ToString();`

Comment: why does everything I post on this site get down-voted, even when I present a correct answer?

Comment: you are not accepting that your answer is wrong..this site is for knowledge sharing and helping and learning...You can learn many things from any part of this site.

Comment: how is it wrong though? he asked why he only see's "10", I told him.

Comment: As per his question..you can see.. he wants to update value every time..not mean that want to concat values everytime..In c# controls values are updated on end of event.So text-box displaying last value that is updated..to update value between the event we have to call Refresh() method.

Comment: I got your question now as did sagram. But you need to better explain your question. From first look its very difficult that you mean this.